# Best practices to MOVE a feature from a published branch to another

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, git-flow

Let's say our release branch looks something like this.

```
* Feature 3
|
* Feature 2
|
* Some fix
|
* Feature 2
|
* Feature 1
```

We are just about to release, but it turns out *Feature 2* has to be dismantled from the release, yet we want to retain the implementation in other temporary branch.

Now, as the release branch is public history, rebasing is out of question. As far as I know, `reverting` all *Feature 2* commits is the only acceptable solution here to not mess up the history.

Now the real question is, what is the most convenient way to retain the feature in temporary branch to be merged into next version release branch? For example, if I branch a topic branch before commiting reverts in the main branch, topic branch is already up-to-date with main branch, but ideally I want to make it ahead of the main branch to merge the feature back in.

I ended up branching *after* the reverts, and reverting the reverts in the temporary branch. This makes the temporary branch storing the feature ahead of the main branch, but this solutions feels somewhat clunky and difficult to understand for others reading the history.

So what is the best practice to solve this kind of situation?

Comment: which commit(s) do you want to move to a temporary branch, the first Feature 2, the second Feature 2 or the three commits (Feature2- Some fix -Feature 2)?

Comment: Only the Feature 2 commits

Answer (score 0):

It’s not make bug difference for whether create the `topic` branch before reverting or after reverting. You just need to cherry-pick the Feature 2 commits to `topic` branch, and then merge `topic` branch into `release` branch for next time.

In order to make it easily to explain, let use Feature 2a and Feature 2b for the two commits:

```
* Feature 3
|
* Feature 2b
|
* Some fix
|
* Feature 2a
|
* Feature 1
```

Assume the `topic` branch is created before reverting (it’s ok to create `topic` after reverting), then you can cherry-pick the commits Feature 2a and Feature 2b to `topic` branch:

```
git checkout -b topic
git cherry-pick <commit id for Feature 2a>
git cherry-pick <commit id for Feature 2b>
```

Then you can reverting Feature 2 commits on the top of release branch, and the commit history will look:

```
* Revert Feature 2b (release)
|
* Revert Feature 2a
| * cherry pick Feature 2b (topic)
| * cherry pick Feature 2a
|/
* Feature 3
|
* Feature 2b
|
* Some fix
|
* Feature 2a
|
* Feature 1
```

For next time release, you can make changes on `release` branch and then merge `topic` branch into `release` branch so that the Feature 2 merged into `release` branch:

```
*  merge topic into release branch (release)
| \
* | make changes
| |
* | Revert Feature 2b 
| |
* | Revert Feature 2a
| * cherry pick Feature 2b (topic)
| * cherry pick Feature 2a
|/
* Feature 3
|
* Feature 2b
|
* Some fix
|
* Feature 2a
|
* Feature 1
```